# How to run 2 different functions with Python 3's multiprocessing Pool?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, multiprocessing

Ok, say I have this code:

```
import time

def helloworld(sleep_time):
    while True:
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        print('Hello world!')

def hellocountry():
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
        print('Hello country!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(3) as p:
        p.map(helloworld, [1, 5, 7])
```

How would I execute hellocountry, while helloworld is being executed? I guess I could write a wrapper function, but that seems rather clumsy and unpythonic.

Comment: use [`.submit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) (I suggest for the `helloworld()` calls too).

Comment: So is Pool() just a wrapper around ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: In your code, `Pool` is undefined. But no, I confused `Pool` and Executor.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`apply_async`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) method.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(3) as p:
        p.apply_async(hellocountry)
        p.map(helloworld, [1, 5, 7])
```